# Returning value within two column when it match 3 criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office

I would like to return a value `4.42295`, if i choose **MYR**. If I choose **SGD** will return `1.32963` as picture show below. I had tried some formula in the picture but seem like cannot solve what i need. Thank for helping me.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Change order of arguments in `INDEX` function, row number first, then column number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, you need to use the following formula in order to accomplish the desired output:

[image]

---

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$7:$E$19,MATCH(1,(G2>=A7:A19)*(G2<=B7:B19),0),MATCH(I2,C6:E6,0)),0)
```

---

Or, If using `MS365` then use `XLOOKUP()`+`FILTER()` or `Double XLOOKUP()`

```
=XLOOKUP(1,(G2>=A7:A19)*(G2<=B7:B19),FILTER(C7:E19,C6:E6=I2,""),"")
```

---

Or,

```
=XLOOKUP(1,(G2>=A7:A19)*(G2<=B7:B19),XLOOKUP(I2,C6:E6,C7:E19))
```

---

However, from the screenshot in OP, it seems you are using `Google-Sheets` if so then use the following formula:

[image]

---

```
=IFNA(FILTER(XLOOKUP(I2,C6:E6,C7:E19,0),(G2>=A7:A19)*(G2<=B7:B19)),0)
```

---

Comment: Thanks, it exactly what I'm need it.

Comment: hi Mayukh Bhattacharya, wondering how to make this Filter XLookup working with Arrayformula?

Comment: @AnakinTeow but why do you need it with `ARRAYFORMULA()` when it is already working without it

Comment: that's because i want the formula to run when i enter a new row of amount without copying the formula over and over.

Comment: Hi Mayukh, attached with the google sheet link
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_X-vSX1HTaK5y4JjVYwn5Rm7LpM0nRKKbxaKEDeTyIg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi Mayukh, thanks a lot.